# What is the best way of using this string value in c#?

Tags: c#, html, string

Whats the best way to make the following HTML text block a hardcoded string object in c#? I need it for a test can't use the @ operator since it just stops at the first ". Any ideas?

====================================================

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<HTML>

<HEAD>

  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

  <TITLE>Example Web Page</TITLE>

</HEAD> 

<body>  

<p>You have reached this web page by typing &quot;example.com&quot;,

&quot;example.net&quot;,&quot;example.org&quot

  or &quot;example.edu&quot; into your web browser.</p>

<p>These domain names are reserved for use in documentation and are not available 

  for registration. See <a href="http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt">RFC 

  2606</a>, Section 3.</p>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use @ but you have to escape any " as "" (double)

There is no other way as far as I have found.

First lines would then be

```
@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"">

<HTML>
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you put it in a text file that you then embed into the assembly. That way you can edit it with syntax highlighting etc, and it won't clutter up your code.

Use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) to load it again at execution time. If you do this a fair amount, you might want to write helper methods to do it more easily.

Comment: Example for loading : private static void GetStandardDocument()
  {
   using (Stream stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("<your namespace path here>.<your filename here>"))
   {
    if (stream == null)
     throw new Exception("No standard document could be found!");

    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    stdTemplatedOcument = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
  }

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to embed it like Jon Skeet's answer, you'll have to change all occurences of `"` to `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this link might answer your question:

[Storing HTML tags in a string variable.](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10214566/store-html-tags-in-string-variable-.aspx)

Comment: Which answer on that page are you refering to?

Comment: The same page that opens. I just wanted the original poster to see the String.Format answers there.